# Add a new page in Tag to show all users with tag badges

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges, tag-badges

Would it be possible to add a new page to Tags to show all users who earned a tag badge? This could be a link next to top users (see the image below) and show users grouped by the tag badge type (gold, silver, bronze).

[image: Proposed change]

Comment: There are 3 categories of tag badges. There should be three tabs :P

Comment: +1 for the funny face (and also the feature).

Comment: Or maybe just add links to the tag badge earners inside the top users page.

Comment: You can get to this from the badges page, but adding a link from the tag page would make sense too.

Comment: Related: [Display tag badges on tag page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202250/193139)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this redundant with the "Top Users" tab?

The Top Users is already showing the reputation earned, from there you can already deduce who earned which badge.

The only downside of the Top Users tab is that it shows only Top 20. Perhaps this could be extended to allow browsing through all the users who earned reputation in the given tag.

Comment: It's kind of similar but it would make tag badges a tiny bit more important and prominent.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that having links to tag badges on "top users" page will be quite useful. Currently finding awarded users is really ineffective. How it might look like?

[image]