# Display tag badges on tag page

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, tag-badges

Can we display tag badges on the tag page?

Currently to look at the amount of badge awards for a tag, you have to:

- Go to the badge page
- Scroll down to Tag Badges
- Click on Bronze Badges
- Click on "All"
- Use Ctrl-F to find the one you're looking for (faster than scrolling)
- Process desired information

Wouldn't this be much simpler?

- Go to the tag page
- Process desired information

As an example (for [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm), to be displayed on the right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/algorithm/info)):

[image]

Comment: Related: [Add a new page in Tag to show all users with tag badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200328)